# How do I change the size of the blinking cursor inside the input

Tags: javascript

I want to change size of the input element blinking cursor with CSS how do I do that?

```
   input[caretSize]{
   height: 3px;
}
```

Comment: There might be some browser specific css, but there is no real styles to set it. Some browsers let you change the color: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color

Comment: Have you tried to change the font-size?

Comment: One way to go about it would be to use a custom cursor. You design your cursor to appear as the size you want. Take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/